# How can i make my query parameters to be type safe?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have maked service where I need to send query parameters dynamically.

**METHOD SERVICE**
So I have this method in my `AuctionService`.

```
getBids(id:number, params?: any) {
  return this.http.get(this._GET_AUCTION_URL + '/' + ApiPaths.auction + '/' + id + '/bids', {params});
}
```

From my component when I send the query parameters

**COMPONENT.ts**

```
  let queryParams = {
      filterSupplierName: 'sds',
      filterBidAwardStatus: ['Awarded', 'Ignored']
    }

 this.getAuctionService
    .getAuctionBidsByGuidUsingGET(id, queryParams)
    .subscribe((data) => {
...
```

it makes dynamically the  GET url to be like so

https://some-url/api/22222/bids?filterSupplierName=sds&filterBidAwardStatus=Awarded&filterBidAwardStatus=Ignored

NOW I WANT TO MAKE TYPE SAFETY IN MY query params, so from component when I try to send for example some property which key or values is not correct, to show some compilation error.

So I need to have
`filterSupplierName of type string OR filterBidAwardStatus OF type array of string`.

So when I try that

```
export interface IBidsFilter {
  filterSupplierName: string;
  filterBidAwardStatus: string[];
}
getBids(id:number, params?: IBidsFilter) {
  return this.http.get(this._GET_AUCTION_URL + '/' + ApiPaths.auction + '/' + id + '/bids', {params});
}
```

I get error No overload

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type 'ITest' is not assignable to type 'HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'ITest' is not assignable to type '{ [param: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'ITest'
```

The only solution that I found is adding `as any` but it is not so good solution

```
getBids(id:number, params?: IBidsFilter) {
  return this.http.get(this._GET_AUCTION_URL + '/' + ApiPaths.auction + '/' + id + '/bids', {params: params as any});
}
```

How can I solve this with another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Angular HTTP client expects query parameters with string types only because you can only send string in a URL in the end.

That is it expects `params` to be of type `{ [key:string] : string | string[] }`. *(actually it allows some other variations but that's the idea)*

This means you should convert your `IBidsFilter` to the type above.

*Note that your error talks about a `ITest` that is not part of `IBidsFilter`, I assume you didn't copy the whole definition.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But can you please provide answer - how can i make my interface - IBidsFilter  to be of type  { [key:string] : string | string[] } ?

Comment: Just like you wrote in the comment: `export interface IBidsFilter { [key:string] : string | string[] }`

Comment: @peckoski show us your `ITest` interface because the `IBidsFilter` you shared is already okay.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu but to prevent error that it gives me

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HTTPParams()

```
let queryParams = new HttpParams();
let arr = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl'];
queryParams.set('test',arr[0]);
queryParams.set('test',arr[1]);
queryParams.set('test',arr[2]);
queryParams.set('test',arr[3]);

return this.http.get(`${your-url}`, queryParams);
```

Comment: this will not be dynamically, i don't know how many values i will bne sending into the query params sometimes coul;d be 4 sometims could be 2

Comment: You can do a foreach over the array....

Comment: this does not work if we set array of strings inside

Answer (score 0):

### Spread syntax

```js
getBids(id: number, params?: IBidsFilter) {
    const sendParams = { ...params }
    return this.httpc.get('', { params: sendParams });
}
```

view doc in [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

### If u r looking for array params in http get

```js
getBids(id: number, params?: IBidsFilter) {
    const sendParams: MapOfKey = {};

    Object.keys(params || {}).forEach(key => {
      let value = params[key];
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        sendParams[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        return;
      }

      sendParams[key] = value;
    })

    return this.httpc.get('', { params: sendParams });
}

export type MapOfKey = {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

That result is like

```js
http://localhost:4200/?filterSupplierName=nailon&filterBidAwardStatus=%5B%221%22,%222%22%5D
```

Comment: why shpuld it work with making copy of the object ?

Comment: it does not work on ththis way

Comment: @peckoski What  u mean it does not work? If u mean array params in http get, use `JSON.stringify`  make array to string